# The expression "ne pas rapporter un radis à quelqu’un"

Tags: sens, usage

> Quoi qu'il en soit, voilà de quoi donner tort à ceux qui prétendent que la musique ***ne leur rapporte pas un radis***.

I just cannot seem to find a dictionary entry for this expression anywhere. I assume that it is close in meaning to "ne servir à rien à quelqu’un", but is it an informal expression that is almost always used in negative?

I usually associate the verb "rapporter” with some sort of monetary gain, but I wonder if this expression too is about whether something is lucrative or not. Or does it extend to benefits in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ton intuition qu'il s'agit d'argent est tout à fait juste. *Ne pas rapporter un radis* signifie ne rapporter aucun gain financier. Dans un dictionnaire tu aurais trouvé plus facilement l'expression *ne plus avoir un radis* comme dans [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/images/Ne_pas_avoir_un_radis_par_Soledad/1309980) ou [*500 Expressions Françaises*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HRfECQAAQBAJ&pg=PT192&lpg=PT192&dq=%22ne%20pas%20avoir%20un%20radis%22&source=bl&ots=IJhNocgCpm&sig=px7Thy1ybWFCdWEzvnDTln8C1RM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8oOuz1rnWAhXDKFAKHX6bBy04ChDoAQgvMAM#v=onepage&q=%22ne%20pas%20avoir%20un%20radis%22&f=false). Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/radis) (B) le signale aussi.
Comme tu le soupçonnes encore l'emploi du mot dans ce sens ne se trouve presque uniquement que dans des expressions négatives, comme *ne pas avoir un radis* ou *ne pas rapporter un radis*. Le TLF donne un exemple d'emploi dans un sens positif :

> Comme j' m'en allais, la marchande Me d'mand' trois ronds. − C'est chaud, qu' j'y dis Mais quéqu' vous vouliez que j' marchande? Et j'y ai été d' mes trois radis. (A. Bruant)

Dans cette phrase le *radis* reprèsente une petite pièce de monnaie.

On trouve le mot *radis* attesté pour la première fois dans ce sens argotique dans le *Dictionnaire de la langue verte* d'[Alfred Delvau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Delvau) (1866).

> **Radis** n.m.Pièce de monnaie, argent quelconque,— dans l'argot des faubouriens.
>   *N'avoir pas un radis* être tout à fait pauvre.<sup>1</sup>

Mais *Le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (1992) signale sa première apparition en 1842 :

> Au figuré, n'avoir plus un radis (1842) signifie « n'avoir plus d'argent », le *radis* symbolisant, comme plusieurs noms de petits fruits et légumes désignant une chose de peu (*nèfles*, etc.), une petite somme d'argent.

On peut aussi consulter  *[La Bible du Radis](http://www.passeportsante.net/fr/Nutrition/EncyclopedieAliments/Fiche.aspx?doc=radis_nu)* sur le site Passeport Santé.

> **Radis, richesse et pauvreté**
>   Dans la langue populaire du XIXe siècle, le terme « radis » désignait une petite pièce de monnaie, puis il a pris le sens de « petite quantité d’argent ». D’où l’expression « ne plus avoir un radis » qui persiste encore aujourd’hui. Pour les Grecs de l’Antiquité, c’était l’inverse. Ils portaient un tel respect à ce légume que leurs offrandes de radis au dieu Apollon étaient présentées dans des assiettes en or. La betterave et le navet n’avaient droit qu’à l’argent et au plomb.

<sup>1</sup> À consulter sur [Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50521b/f416.image).

Comment: On peut aussi dire quelque chose comme "Rien ! Pas un radis !", pour insister sur "rien".